# RAM size minimum required for Dual booting windows 10 and ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I have a hp laptop and its specifications are 4GB RAM and AMD A8 processor.Is it preferable to dual boot it with windows 10 and ubuntu

Comment: The ram requirements for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS are 2GB (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)  Dual booting means you can boot either of two (or more) Operating Systems, but only one is running at any time; hence the requirements are the same as for a single OS.

Comment: Same question on Super User: [Does dual booting split RAM between the two systems?](https://superuser.com/q/1315469/443564)

Answer (score 2):

With dual-booting, the two OS's are not running at the same time, so RAM is not a factor, as long as you have enough to run one OS at a time. [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) and [Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/windows-10-specifications#primaryR2) need 2GB, so you're good to go.

Though if you **do** want to run both OS's at a time, you could run one inside the other on a virtual machine (e.g. using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)).